# How to use scope in an association relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, associations

## Background

1. I have `User`
2. I have `Event`
3. `User` can attend many `Events`
4. I have an `EventUser` "through" table.
5. I have an association called `:events_attending` on the `User` model.
6. I have `past` and `future` scopes on `Event`

## What I'm trying to achieve

I want to be able to split the events a user is attending/has attended using syntax similar to below - whatever the correct equivalent is.

```rb
current_user.events_attending.past
```

But I understand that I cannot, because `events_attending` is an association, and even then, my understanding is that it's an association to `EventUser`, and not `Event`. So the scope still couldn't be applied.

How can I manage this such that I can do something like what I've shown in that line of code above?

## Helpful source code

`Event.rb`:

```rb
class Event < ApplicationRecord    
    scope :future, -> { where("time > datetime()") }
    scope :past, -> { where("time < datetime()") }

    has_many :event_user
    has_many :attendees, through: :event_user, source: :user
    belongs_to :author, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
end
```

`User.rb`

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events
  has_many :events_attending, class_name: "EventUser"
end
```

`EventUser.rb`

```rb
class EventUser < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user 
    belongs_to :event
end
```

I removed things like devise traits and validations, for brevity.

I appreciate your time, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try setting your `Event.rb` class and `User.rb` class this way and see if it works?

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord    
    scope :future, -> { where("time > datetime()") }
    scope :past, -> { where("time < datetime()") }

    has_many :event_users # Note that this needs to be plural
    has_many :attendees, through: :event_user, source: :user
    belongs_to :author, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events_attending, class_name: "EventUser"
  has_many :events, through: :events_attending, source: :event
end
```

Then you can call the user's past events through `current_user.events.past`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Getting this -> `(undefined method 'past' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<EventUser...`

Comment: Sorry, no, you're right if I access `events` through `User`. However, I want `user.events` to be reserved for events the user has created, whereas `user.events_attending` should be a list of events the user is going to.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of limciana's helpful answer, I modified the associations in the User.rb class as follows:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :event_user
  has_many :events_attending, through: :event_user, source: :event
  has_many :events  
end
```

I think the problem previously was that my `user.events_attending` expression would return `EventUser` records. But if I simply set it to return `Events`, *through* `EventUser`, then the `past` and `future` scopes seem to work seamlessly.

i.e. I can now do

```rb
current_user.events_attending.past
```

or

```rb
current_user.events_attending.future
```

and it works.